# <Tag> does not exist on this site

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I am attempting to add "Poem" in my watched Tag. It shows in suggestion also.

On selecting that suggestion and clicking Add, gives me error that "Poem does not exist on this site".

If the tag does not really exist, why does it show up in suggestion? I later found that "Poem" tag is marked synonym to "Poetry" tag.

Can there be better experience or at least not show synonyms in suggestion?

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that [poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poem) is a *proposed* synonym for [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry). The [poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poem) tag itself was removed from the system some months ago on account of going unused. This is a fairly routine situation, but what we neglected to do was exclude synonyms that haven't been approved yet from the autocomplete lookup.

The fix is out in production now.

Thanks for the report!